# Как ускорить в python преобразование огромного списка/кортежа русских слов в нормальную форму?

Tags: python, оптимизация, nlp, pymorphy2, морфология

Есть потребность преобразовывать на регулярной основе большие списки русских слов в нормальную форму.
Популярная библиотека **Pymorphy2** работает очень качественно, но очень медленно на больших количествах слов в циклах. Например, 880 тыс. слов на моём компьютере (AMD Phenom II X6 1090T, 3617 MHz, 20Гб ОЗУ) обрабатывает 4 минуты вот в таком коде:

```
import pymorphy2
morph = pymorphy2.MorphAnalyzer()
<...>
lst_newlist = [morph.parse(str_word)[0].normal_form for str_word in tuple_somewords]
```

Экспериментировал с массивами **numpy** - ускорения не получил. Всё равно упирался в цикл **for**.
Пытался распараллелить c помощью библиотеки **joblib**  - тоже не получил ускорения.

В самой библиотеке **Pymorphy2**, насколько я понял, проблема в том, что она не заточена на обработку массивов/списков слов - при каждом вызове очередного слова снова загружает в память свои словари и выполняет  одну и ту же рутину, которую можно было бы по-хорошему сделать один раз перед обработкой списка, а не одного слова.

Копаться и переделывать код **Pymorphy2** не готов.

**Pymystem3** работает значительно быстрее (раза в четыре), но по идеалогическим причинам не хочу загружать скомпилированные exe файлы на компьютер. И, похоже, что при каждом обращении к **Pymystem3** требуется доступ к интернет, иначе вываливаются ошибки исполнения.

Стемминг категорически не пригоден.

Есть ли возможность ускорить **Pymorphy2**? Или, может быть, есть другие качественные и быстрые библиотеки для преобразования русских слов в нормальную форму?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте закешировать результат (если память позволяет):

```
import pymorphy2

morph = pymorphy2.MorphAnalyzer()
norm = {}

def norm_form(word):
    res = norm.get(word)
    if res:
        return res
    res = morph.parse(word)[0].normal_form
    norm[word] = res
    return res

lst_newlist = [norm_form(str_word) for str_word in tuple_somewords]
```

---

Можно также воспользоваться [встроенным Python cache декоратором](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cache), как советует @insolor:

```
from functools import lru_cache

# начиная с Python 3.9 можно использовать `@cache` вместо `@lru_cache(maxsize=None)`
@lru_cache(maxsize=None) 
def norm_form_cached(word):
    return morph.parse(word)[0].normal_form
```

Сравнение скорости обработки для ~202.000 слов (роман "Идиот" Достоевского):

```
In [61]: with open("idiot.txt") as f:
    ...:     data = f.read()
    ...:

In [62]: %time norm_words = [morph.parse(word)[0].normal_form for word in word_tokenize(data) if word.isalpha()]
CPU times: user 35.9 s, sys: 42.8 ms, total: 36 s
Wall time: 36.1 s

In [63]: norm = {}

In [64]: %time norm_words = [norm_form(word) for word in word_tokenize(data) if word.isalpha()]
CPU times: user 4.25 s, sys: 7.62 ms, total: 4.26 s
Wall time: 4.27 s

In [65]: len(norm_words)
Out[65]: 202336

In [66]: 36.1 / 4.27
Out[66]: 8.45433255269321

In [83]: %time norm_words = [norm_form_cached(word) for word in word_tokenize(data) if word.isalpha()]
CPU times: user 4.18 s, sys: 8.45 ms, total: 4.19 s
Wall time: 4.2 s
```

Выигрыш в ~8.5 раз.
Статистика использования кеша:

```
In [84]: norm_form_cached.cache_info()
Out[84]: CacheInfo(hits=174582, misses=27754, maxsize=None, currsize=27754)
```

Дальше можно попробовать обрабатывать текст параллельно, разбив текст на куски.

Comment: Ловко! До кэширования не додумался. Спасибо за совет! Проверю на свежую голову. Выглядит правдоподобно! Может и распараллеливать не потребуется.

Comment: Проверил. Работает идеально. Лемматизация ускорилась примерно в 5 раз! Такой способ работы с pymorphy2, мне кажется, надо в документацию прописать, как стандартный :-)

Comment: @SergL нет смысла все конкретные юзкейсы тянуть в документацию. Если кому-то нужно обработать одно слово в секунду, а не миллион слов, ему "стандартный" способ с кешированием не нужен будет.

Comment: @MaxU, для кеширования можно декоратор [`@lru_cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) использовать

Comment: Или просто [`@cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cache), если Python 3.9 и выше

Comment: @insolor, спасибо, добавил вариант с `@lrcu)cache` в ответ )

Comment: @insolor, это очевидно. Речь не об этом. Я счёл, что такой вариант расширяет функциональность библиотеки и оценил его, как один из стандартных вариантов её применения. Других смыслов не ищите...

Comment: @insolor, какие последствия для памяти при использовании **@cache**, можете подсказать? Можно ли управлять этим кэшем, не возникнет ли переполнение памяти с ошибкой исполнения, если запускать в цикле по многу раз? Впервые работаю с питоном, нет здесь практического опыта совсем.

Comment: @SergL, параметр `maxsize=...` позволяет указать максимальное количество элементов в кеше - это поможет найти компромис между использованием памяти и скоростью обработки...

Comment: Спасибо за советы! Проверил с **@cache**. С этим декоратором ещё быстрее сработала (в моём случае на 5 секунд), чем с ручным созданием и пополнением словаря. Подозреваю, что функция @cache нечто похожее внутри себя делает:-)

Comment: @SergL, да, [именно это она под капотом и делает](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/functools.py#L525-L621) ;)